# Find the content in the first open brace regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Assuming that we have the following content which has three lines:

```
cnt1 {\abc asd{} sd {{d}} def.}
cnt2 {\abc hgj{} sd {sd} {{d}} def.}
cnt3 {\def asd{} sd {{d}} def.}
```

As we can see, many open and close braces here, can I filter both the content in the first line and the second line, it has similar content "{\abc" and the beginning of each line, but each one has difference number of braces and content inside. I just think about this problem is how to detect the content of the first opening brace (parent braces) of each line which its starting content is "\abc".

Assuming that the content "{\abc asd{} sd {{d}} def.}" = $1, and "{\abc hgj{} sd {sd} {{d}} def.}" = $2. How I can make the desired result as

```
cnt1 x$1y
cnt2 g$2h
cnt3 {\def asd{} sd {{d}} def.}
```

(x,y and g,h is added to two sides of the given content)
Thank you so much!

Comment: Please take a look at my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple regex like this: `{\\abc.*}`

```
    String str = 
            "cnt1 {\\abc asd{} sd {{d}} def.}\n" +
            "cnt2 {\\abc hgj{} sd {sd} {{d}} def.}\n" +

            "cnt3 {\\def asd{} sd {{d}} def.}\n";
    Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("\\{\\\\abc.*}");
    Matcher matcher=pat.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
```

Obviously `{` had to be escaped

Output:

```
{\abc asd{} sd {{d}} def.}
{\abc hgj{} sd {sd} {{d}} def.}
```

Comment: I would like to do this in Notepad++